# Is the space of continuous local martingales equipped with the topology of uniform convergence on compact sets complete?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, local-martingales

Let

- $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ be a probability space
- $(\mathcal F_t)_{t\ge0}$ be a filtration on $(\Omega,\mathcal A)$
- $M_{c,\:\text{loc}}(\mathcal F,\operatorname P)$ denote the set of continuous local $\mathcal F$-martingales on $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$

Is $M_{c,\:\text{loc}}(\mathcal F,\operatorname P)$ equipped with the topology of uniform convergence on compact sets$^1$ complete?

---

$^1$ i.e. If $(M^n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq M_{c,\:\text{loc}}(\mathcal F,\operatorname P)$ and $M\in M_{c,\:\text{loc}}(\mathcal F,\operatorname P)$, then $M_n\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}M$ in $M_{c,\:\text{loc}}(\mathcal F,\operatorname P)$ if and only if $$\sup_{0\le s\le t}\left|M^n_s-M_s\right|\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0\;\;\;\text{in probability for all }t\ge 0\tag1.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the space of continuous local martingales equipped with ucp convergence is complete.

Let $(M^n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq M_{c,\text{loc}}(\mathcal{F},P)$ be a Cauchy sequence with respect to the ucp convergence. Then we can choose for any fixed $T>0$ numbers $n_k \in \mathbb{N}$, $n_1 < n_2 < \ldots$, such that

$$\mathbb{P} \left( \sup_{t \leq T} |M^{n_k}_s-M_s^{n_{k-1}}|>2^{-k} \right) \leq 2^{-k}.$$

By the Borel Cantelli lemma, this implies that

$$\mathbb{P} \left( \sup_{t \leq T} |M^{n_k}_t-M_t^{n_{k-1}}|>2^{-k} \, \, \text{for infinitely many $k$} \right)=0.$$

Using that

$$M_t^n - M_t^m = \sum_{k=m+1}^n (M_t^k-M_t^{k-1}), \qquad m<n,$$

it is not difficult to see that this implies that $(M_t^{n_k}(\omega))_{t \leq T}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $C([0,T],\|\cdot\|_{\infty})$ for $\mathbb{P}$-almost all $\omega$. By the completeness of $C[0,T]$, we find that

$$M_t(\omega) := \lim_{k \to \infty} M_t^{n_k}(\omega)$$

exists almost surely and defines a process with continuous sample paths. Since $(M^n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a Cauchy sequence with respec to the ucp convergence and $M^{n_k} \to M$ uniformly on $[0,T]$ with probability $1$, it follows that

$$\forall \epsilon>0: \quad \lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{P} \left( \sup_{t \leq T} |M_t^n-M_t|> \epsilon \right)=0,$$

and so $M^n \to M$ in ucp. Consequently, $M$ is the ucp limit of a sequence of continuous local martingales, and so $M$ is itself a local martingale (see Theorem 5 [here](https://almostsure.wordpress.com/2009/12/24/local-martingales/)).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually, I've figured it out in the meantime. However, I've got one remaining question: Your proof above can be generalized to the following scenario: Let $M$ be a metric space and $E$ be a $\mathbb R$-Banach space. Now, let $\mathcal B_{\text{loc}}(\mathcal A;M,E)$ denote the set of $F:\Omega\times M\to E$ with $F(\;\cdot\;,x)$ being $\mathcal A$-measurable for all $x\in M$ and $$\left\|F(\omega,\;\cdot\;)\right\|_{B(K,\:E)}:=\sup_{x\in K}\left\|F(\omega,x)\right\|_E<\infty\;\;\;\text{for all }\omega\in\Omega\text{ and compact }K\subseteq M.$$

Comment: Now, assume $(F_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq\mathcal B_{\text{loc}}(\mathcal A;M,E)$ with $$\left\|F_m-F_n\right\|_{B(K,\:E)}\xrightarrow{m,\:n\:\to\:\infty}0\;\;\;\text{in probability for all compact }K\subseteq M.$$ With the same arguments as in your proof, we can show that there is a $F:\Omega\times M\to E$ with $F(\;\cdot\;,x)$ being $\mathcal A$-measurable for all $x\in M$ and $$\left\|F_n-F\right\|_{B(K,\:E)}\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0\;\;\;\text{in probability for all compact }K\subseteq M.$$

Comment: However, it's not clear to me whether $F\in B_{\text{loc}}(\mathcal A;M,E)$, i.e. whether $\left\|F(\omega,\;\cdot\;)\right\|_{B(K,\:E)}<\infty$ (at least for almost) all $\omega\in\Omega$ for all compact $K\subseteq M$.

Comment: @0xbadf00d I'm somewhat puzzled about your question. If (as you say) $\|F_n-F\|_{B(K,E)} \to 0$ in probability, then $$\mathbb{P}(\exists n: \|F_n-F\|_{B(K,E)}<\infty) =1$$ and so $$\|F\|_{B(K,E)} \leq \|F_n-F\|_{B(K,E)} + \|F_n\|_{B(K,E)} < \infty$$ with probability $1$... or am I missing something?

Comment: You're missing nothing. As you say, it's trivial. Don't know what I was thinking. However, in order to prove that $M$ is a local martingale, it seems like we need the fact that $$A_t:=\sup_{n\in\mathbb N}\sup_{s\in[0,\:t]}\left\|M_s^n\right\|_E\;\;\;\text{for }t\ge0$$ is continuous. But I don't see why that's the case. I've asked a [separate question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2806538/show-that-the-supremum-of-a-sequence-of-continuous-functions-is-continuous) for that, but the downvotes indicate that it is either trivial or obviously wrong.

Comment: @0xbadf00d I don't have much time right now to think about it (or to look at the question you linked) ,but why would we need that $A_t$ is continuous...`?

Comment: It would allow us to conclude that $\inf\left\{t\ge0:A_t\ge C\right\}$ is a stopping time. And it's claimed [here](https://books.google.de/books?id=_S1RiCosqbMC&pg=PA44&lpg=PA44&dq=%22then+it+is+a+continuous+increasing+process%22&source=bl&ots=ikbzvbhJv0&sig=lbXnsnK1Vf9JQZWTTSwdiRkBPhk&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiivJjx6L_bAhWQJVAKHSmCA_QQ6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q=%22then%20it%20is%20a%20continuous%20increasing%20process%22&f=false).

Comment: There is a remaining issue in your first comment: With my definition, $F\in B_{\text{loc}}(\mathcal A;M,E)$ iff $\left\|F(\omega,\;\cdot\;)\right\|_{B(K,\:E)}<\infty$ for **all** $\omega\in\Omega$. You've shown that $\operatorname P\left[\left\|F\right\|_{B(K,\:E)}<\infty\right]=1$ for all compact $K\subseteq M$, but the null set depends on $K$. So, I don't see how we can conclude, unless $M$ is $\sigma$-compact.

Comment: @0xbadf00d Just set it equal to some fixed element $e \in E$ for any $\omega$ for which the norm is infinite.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what you mean. Let $K\subseteq M$ be compact. There is a $N_K\in\mathcal A$ with $\operatorname P[N_K]=0$ and $\left\|F(\omega)\right\|_{B(K,\:E)}<\infty$ for all $\omega\in\Omega\setminus N_K$. Now, if $M$ is not $\sigma$-compact, $M$ cannot be covered by countable many $K$ and the union of the $N_K$ doesn't need to be a null set.

Comment: @0xbadf00d I see; actually I think that the $\sigma$-finiteness is already needed to construct $F$ (at least if you want to use the construction which I used in my answer). Could you, however, please consider opening a new question? It's pretty annoying to discuss this in the comments and, moreover, it is only partially related to your original question.

Comment: It's not needed for the construction of $F$. $F$ is constructed as you did with the property that $F^n(x)\to F(x)$ in probability for all $x$. It's then simple to show that this already implies that $F^n\to F$ on any compact subset in probability. The $\sigma$-compactness is only needed for the selection of a null set and hence to obtain that $F$ is indistinguishable to a process belonging to $B_{\text{loc}}(\mathcal A;M,E)$. At least if I'm not missing something.